How to remove a special character like ⏩ and ’ using Regex in C#
So I have the following string that I am getting from an XML source:
string text=@" ⏩ മരണം << രണ്ടാം പാപ്പാനായ >> മകന്റെ കൺമുന്നിൽ ’’";
If you will see the character set here, I am getting the exact character ⏩ and ’’ from the XML source.
I am able to remove the << and >> using the following regex:
[^\\u0900-\\u0dff^\\u0000-\\u00ff]
But the top characters are not being removed. Can you please direct me on how to go on handling such characters?
.NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/E4fL9c
Regex 101: https://regex101.com/r/6dW1qZ/1

why regex instead of simple string.replace?

@RandRandom There is a character range here that I have to handle which includes -, @, # etc so cannot build a dictionary here since it will too long for handling these special characters.

@RahulSharma it's unclear what you mean by "special characters".  While ⏩ is an uncommon Unicode character, < and > are part of US-ASCII. There's nothing special about these. XML has no problem with any of these. In any case you didn't post any code that replaces those characters. The pattern you posted doesn't do what you assume and the code in the fiddle escapes the pattern instead of using it.

What are you actually trying to do? Explain the actual requirement, not how you think it can be done. \\u0000-\\u00ff matches English letters, whitespace and a lot of unprintable characters. It will capture space for example but not Cyrillic. If you want to capture or exclude Malaysian characters you can use a named group, eg \p{IsMalayalam} or \P{IsMalayalam}. You could use [\p{IsMalayalam}\s] to capture only Malaysian and whitespace characters. What output do you expect from the question's text?

Define special, which exact characters?

You can use [^(\p{IsMalayalam}|\s)] as the search pattern to retain Malaysian and whitespace. https://dotnetfiddle.net/6Ce3lg, returning "  മരണം  രണ്ടാം പാപ്പാനായ   മകന്റെ കൺമുന്നിൽ ". If you remove \s, or you use just \P{IsMalayalam} you only get Malaysian characters മരണംരണ്ടാംപാപ്പാനായമകന്റെകൺമുന്നിൽ

Why?  Is first line of xml UTF-8 or something else.  Try skipping first line and see if you still get an error.  C# will give error when not UTF-8.  The first line of xml is not needed.

@PanagiotisKanavos Thank you very much. I was not aware of the IsMalayalam group in regex. My end output is only to get the Malayalam characters but retaining the white-spaces and remove all other characters. Are these regex groups documented somewhere?

Yes, they are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions  (found using: Google)

It seems you're trying to remove any non-Malayalam characters. The Unicode standard has several predefined blocks eg Letter, Punctuation and language-specific ranges.
In .NET regular expressions you can include characters in a Unicode named block with \p{Name} or exclude them with \P{Name}. In the question's case you can replace all non-Malayalam characters with :
var text2=Regex.Replace(str, @"\P{IsMalayalam}", "");

